# WebStorm: How to prettify HTML in quotes within a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm

I have the following block in my `app.component.ts` file:

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li>
    <!-- each hero goes here -->
  </li>
</ul>
    <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})
```

How can I tell WebStorm to prettify my JS as well as the HTML that is inside the quotes?

I have already tried: `Code > Auto-indent Lines` and `Code > Reformat Code`

I am using **WebStorm 2016.3**

Comment: try copy and paste in an html file, than copy paste the prettified version on top of the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Edit Angular2HTML Fragment` intention:

[image]

To bring it up, just click `Ctrl+Enter` on the string.
It will open editor, where you can prettify code and the changes will be reflected in the string.